# Difference between WebApiConfig.cs and RouteConfig.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

What is the difference between `WebApiConfig.cs` and `RouteConfig.cs` in the `App_Start` folder of an MVC Web API project in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following are the key differences:

1. RouteConfig.cs is exclusively for configuring ASP.NET routes.
2. WebApiConfig.cs is for any Web API related configuration, including Web-API-specific routes, Web API services, and other Web API settings.

As cmotley mentions, the ASP.NET web site includes a good listing of what types of configuration can be done in WebApiConfig.cs in [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Is it okay if I remove RouteConfig and BundleConfig?

Comment: If you don't use them, yes it's OK to remove them.

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference as they both accomplish the same thing - adding routes to your route collection. [You don't need to use the WebApiConfig class; it's simply a convenient way to organize your code.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Yes, those files are just a convention to separate routing concerns between MVC and Web API. You can even register all the routes from the Application_Start method of the Global.asax.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are familiar with ASP.NET MVC, Web API routing is very similar to MVC routing. The main difference is that Web API uses the HTTP method, not the URI path, to select the action. You can also use MVC-style routing in Web API. This article does not assume any knowledge of ASP.NET MVC.

From [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)