# New MVC4 project with Webapi contains WebApiConfig and RouteConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created a new MVC4 Webapi based project and in the App start folder there are several files.  I noticed in the RouteConfig.cs file

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And in WebApiConfig.cs

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now from what I can tell they are both doing the roughly same thing, except one uses .MapRoute and the other .MapHttpRoute of which the parameters are slightly different in notation.  Are these two different routes for different aspects on the application?  Do they need to be in both places?  If so/not which takes precedence?

I found 
[Difference between WebApiConfig.cs and RouteConfig.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017188/difference-between-usage-of-webapiconfig-cs-and-routeconfig-cs)

However all it says is one is for Asp.Net routes and the other is for WebApi routes, but I don't see the difference in usage between the two route types.

Answer (score 1):

That looks odd to me. I just created a new Web API project in Visual Studio 2013 and my WebApiConfig.cs looks like the following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Notice there is no {action} component to the routeTemplate. That's because the action in Web API is determined by the HTTP verb that is used with the request.

The one that is configured in the RouteConfig is used by MVC where you can explicitly provide the controller and action.

Comment: Odd, I've created two or three separate projects and what you've cut and pasted in is what I see... I take it then it interprets the name of the method in the controller by the {id} component of the routetemplate  ie... class MyTestController -> method MyTestMethod is called http://localhost/mytestcontroller/mytestmethod  now I'm wondering how my call IS working when the routetemplatehas an action defined in it!

Comment: By default, in Web API the method is determined by the HTTP verb used to send the request (as mentioned in my original post). That is, the methods on the ApiController will be Get, Post, Put, and Delete. The id is passed to the method as appropriate. If you do a File -> New -> Web API project and then open the ValuesController (assuming VS2013 and the latest templates) you'll see it.

Comment: @CraigW. He is targeting .net 4.0 you are targeting .net 4.5